# Cannot restart mobile application after each test using Protractor and Appium

Tags: android, automation, protractor, appium

I'm new to automation and I have started writing tests with Protractor. 
I have put 5 tests in spec and I need to reset Android application after each test (not to uninstall, just to clear data).

In my conf file I have put noReset to true, fullReset to false, also tried with noReset to false.

I tried to put driver.quit() in last test, but that just closes app, and next test fails since it's not started again.
Tried browser.driver.resetApp() in AfterAll() and it's not working either, same for browser.driver.closeApp() (just wanted to see if it will work).

Can someone help me what should I put in my conf file and in my tests, since after few hours of looking and trying I'm really frustrated. :)

Protractor version 4.0.10
Appium version 1.6.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For me `driver.reset()` worked in after all block